# Analogous of %= using new style interpolation

Tags: python

Consider the strings

```
string_0 = '%s test'
string_1 = '{} test'
```

Imagine now the desired output is to return the formatted string using the variable `x = 'A'`.

For the first case there is an easy and elegant solution:

```
string_0 %= x
print(string_0)
# A test
```

Is there something similar for the second case? E.g.

```
string_1 f= x    # Unfortunately does not work
print(string_1)
# A test
```

**Addressing the comments/responses**

1. I realise `string_1` is not an f-string but Python won't allow f-strings with empty expression
2. I know `f'{x} test'` works perfectly well but requires knowing `x` before the creation.
3. The `format` solutions is also something I'm familiar with but when comparing `s = s.format(x)` to `s %= x` I find not very smooth

**PS** 
Anticipating the responses, I wanted to edit the above part in my question but was not able due to the simultaneous edit.

Comment: That's not an f-string

Comment: If you have the joy of using modern python versions (3.6 and beyond), just do `string_2 = f"{x} test"`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well Yeah: `SyntaxError: f-string: empty expression not allowed`

Comment: @carlsegg97. It's not a dupe. Three title similarity is a mistake in nomenclature on OP's part.

Comment: @user101. OP's code doesn't have that problem anywhere.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah I'm OP :D And what I meant is I believe you misunderstood the question slightly and hence modified the title: `string_1` is not an f-string because something like `string_1 = f'{} test'` will yield the above exception

Comment: @user101. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I looked at your code instead of the title. I'll go get some sleep now.

Comment: @user101. Either way, the answer seems to be to use `str.format` instead of f-strings. May I close your question then?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes sure

Answer (score 1):

New-style string formatting doesn't use an operator and therefore doesn't have an `__i*__`-method overloaded (as old-style formatting does with `__imod__`).

You could directly use an f-string:

```
string_1 = f"{x} test"
```

Other than that, you'll have to be explicit and use

```
string_1 = string_1.format(x)
```

Comment: Thanks, the `__i*__` section helped me understanding it better

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are immutable, `a %= b` is pretty much exactly equivalent to `a = a % b`. The new style equivalent to the [old style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) [`%`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) operator is the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method:

```
string_1 = string_1.format(x)
```